# Closed form for a family of integrals of the form $\int_{0}^{\infty}\Phi(x)x^{m}\cosh(x)dx$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty}\Phi(x)x^{m}\sinh(x)dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, closed-form, riemann-zeta

The above $\Phi(x)$ is related to the Riemann's $\xi(s)$ function.

Specifically
$$
\Phi(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2\pi^{2}n^{4}e^{9x}-3\pi n^{2}e^{5x})\exp(-\pi n^{2}e^{4x})
$$
As stated above, I'm looking for a closed form for the family of integrals
$$
\begin{align*}
S_{m}&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\Phi(x) x^{m}\sinh(x)dx\\
C_{n}&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\Phi(x) x^{n}\cosh(x)dx\\
\end{align*}
$$
Where $n\in \mathbb{N}_{0}$

I was able to find $C_0$, i.e.
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\Phi(x) \cosh(x)dx=\frac{1}{16}
$$

It'd be interesting to see if there are closed forms for the other cases, $S_m, S_n$ ;).

Comment: I think it would be useful to show how you did get $C_0$, or at least how you approached the problem.